# How can I automatically sign in users in a phpBB3 forum based on accounts in a Rails app?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I have a mobile app that uses Rails/MySQL as a backend (just serves JSON, I know we don't need full blown Rails, but this was the simplest solution to get started).  My Rails app uses devise for auth.  I'd like my users to be able to also access a Phpbb3 forum without having to sign up again.  What's the best way to do this?  Have the Phpbb3 forum read accounts right from the same MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Use the email address as a base.

name a file inside includes/ucp called ucp_my_rails_app_connect.php

```
<?php
/*
 * @package     My Package
 * @author      Me
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 * @link       my href
 * @copyright (c) my copyright
 *
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License

 *
 */
/*
* @ignore
*/
if (!defined('IN_PHPBB'))
{
    exit;
}
  /*
  * ucp_myclass
  * my rails app connect
   * @package       my package
  */
class ucp_my_rails_app_connect
{
  var $u_action;

  function main($id, $mode)
  {
    global $config, $db, $user, $auth, $template, $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx;

    /** Do some DB code here for rails or wrap it in a private function*/

    $server_url = generate_board_url();  
    $key_len = 54 - strlen($server_url);
    $key_len = max(6, $key_len); // we want at least 6
    $key_len = ($config['max_pass_chars']) ? min($key_len, $config['max_pass_chars']) : $key_len; // we want at most $config['max_pass_chars']
    $user_actkey = substr(gen_rand_string(10), 0, $key_len);
    $new_user_password = gen_rand_string(8);
    $data = array(
        'username'          => utf8_normalize_nfc(/** rails DB username*/),
        'steam_id'          => request_var('steam_id', ''),             
        'new_password' => $new_user_password,
        'password_confirm' => $new_user_password,           
        'email'             => strtolower(/** rails DB email*/),
        'email_confirm'     => strtolower(/** rails DB email*/)
      );          
    if($my_rails_exec_func == $some_val) /* make some code so not just anyone can submit stuff to this area*/
    {      
      //Check and initialize some variables if needed
      $error = validate_data($data, array(
        'username'          => array(
          array('string', false, $config['min_name_chars'], $config['max_name_chars']),
          array('username', '')),
        'new_password'      => array(
          array('string', false, $config['min_pass_chars'], $config['max_pass_chars']),
          array('password')),
        'password_confirm'  => array('string', false, $config['min_pass_chars'], $config['max_pass_chars']),
        'email'             => array(
          array('string', false, 6, 60),
          array('email')),
        'email_confirm'     => array('string', false, 6, 60),
        'tz'                => array('num', false, -14, 14),
        'lang'              => array('match', false, '#^[a-z_\-]{2,}$#i'),
      ));
      $error = preg_replace('#^([A-Z_]+)$#e', "(!empty(\$user->lang['\\1'])) ? \$user->lang['\\1'] : '\\1'", $error);

      if (!sizeof($error))
      {
        // Which group by default?
        $group_name = ($coppa) ? 'REGISTERED_COPPA' : 'REGISTERED';
        $sql = 'SELECT group_id
          FROM ' . GROUPS_TABLE . "
          WHERE group_name = '" . $db->sql_escape($group_name) . "'
            AND group_type = " . GROUP_SPECIAL;
        $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
        $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
        $db->sql_freeresult($result);

        $group_id = $row['group_id'];
        if (($config['require_activation'] == USER_ACTIVATION_SELF ||
          $config['require_activation'] == USER_ACTIVATION_ADMIN) && $config['email_enable'])
        {
          $user_actkey = gen_rand_string(mt_rand(6, 10));
          $user_type = USER_INACTIVE;
          $user_inactive_reason = INACTIVE_REGISTER;
          $user_inactive_time = time();
        }
        else
        {
          $user_type = USER_NORMAL;
          $user_actkey = '';
          $user_inactive_reason = 0;
          $user_inactive_time = 0;
        }
        $user_row = array(
          'username'                => $data['username'],
          'user_password'           => phpbb_hash($data['new_password']),
          'user_email'          => $data['email'],
          'group_id'                => (int) $group_id,
          'user_timezone'           => (float) $data['tz'],
          'user_dst'                => $is_dst,
          'user_lang'               => $data['lang'],
          'user_type'               => $user_type,
          'user_actkey'         => $user_actkey,
          'user_ip'             => $user->ip,
          'user_regdate'            => time(),
          'user_inactive_reason'    => $user_inactive_reason,
          'user_inactive_time'  => $user_inactive_time,

        );
        if ($config['new_member_post_limit'])
        {
          $user_row['user_new'] = 1;
        }
        // Register user...
        $user_id = user_add($user_row);
        // This should not happen, because the required variables are listed above...
        if ($user_id === false)
        {
          trigger_error('NO_USER', E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        // DB Error
        if(!$result)
        {
          trigger_error('Unable to connect with phpBB database.');
        }

        // Okay, captcha, your job is done.
        if ($config['enable_confirm'] && isset($captcha))
        {
          $captcha->reset();
        }
        if ($coppa && $config['email_enable'])
        {
          $message = $user->lang['ACCOUNT_COPPA'];
          $email_template = 'coppa_welcome_inactive_steam';
        }
        else if ($config['require_activation'] == USER_ACTIVATION_SELF && $config['email_enable'])
        {
          $message = $user->lang['ACCOUNT_INACTIVE'];
          $email_template = 'user_welcome_inactive_steam';
        }
        else if ($config['require_activation'] == USER_ACTIVATION_ADMIN && $config['email_enable'])
        {
          $message = $user->lang['ACCOUNT_INACTIVE_ADMIN'];
          $email_template = 'admin_welcome_inactive_steam';
        }
        else
        {
          $message = $user->lang['ACCOUNT_ADDED'];
          $email_template = 'user_welcome_steam';
        }
        if ($config['email_enable'])
        {
          include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_messenger.' . $phpEx);
          $messenger = new messenger(false);
          $messenger->template($email_template, $data['lang']);
          $messenger->to($data['email'], $data['username']);
          $messenger->headers('X-AntiAbuse: Board servername - ' . $config['server_name']);
          $messenger->headers('X-AntiAbuse: User_id - ' . $user->data['user_id']);
          $messenger->headers('X-AntiAbuse: Username - ' . $user->data['username']);
          $messenger->headers('X-AntiAbuse: User IP - ' . $user->ip);
          $messenger->assign_vars(array(
            'WELCOME_MSG'   => htmlspecialchars_decode(sprintf($user->lang['WELCOME_SUBJECT'], $config['sitename'])),
            'USERNAME'      => htmlspecialchars_decode($data['username']),
            'U_ACTIVATE'    => "$server_url/ucp.$phpEx?mode=activate&u=$user_id&k=$user_actkey")
          );
          if ($coppa)
          {
            $messenger->assign_vars(array(
              'FAX_INFO'        => $config['coppa_fax'],
              'MAIL_INFO'       => $config['coppa_mail'],
              'EMAIL_ADDRESS'   => $data['email'])
            );
          }
          $messenger->send(NOTIFY_EMAIL);
          if ($config['require_activation'] == USER_ACTIVATION_ADMIN)
          {
            // Grab an array of user_id's with a_user permissions ... these users can activate a user
            $admin_ary = $auth->acl_get_list(false, 'a_user', false);
            $admin_ary = (!empty($admin_ary[0]['a_user'])) ? $admin_ary[0]['a_user'] : array();
            // Also include founders
            $where_sql = ' WHERE user_type = ' . USER_FOUNDER;
            if (sizeof($admin_ary))
            {
              $where_sql .= ' OR ' . $db->sql_in_set('user_id', $admin_ary);
            }
            $sql = 'SELECT user_id, username, user_email, user_lang, user_jabber, user_notify_type
              FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' ' .
              $where_sql;
            $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
            while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
            {
              $messenger->template('admin_activate', $row['user_lang']);
              $messenger->to($row['user_email'], $row['username']);
              $messenger->im($row['user_jabber'], $row['username']);
              $messenger->assign_vars(array(
                'USERNAME'          => htmlspecialchars_decode($data['username']),
                'U_USER_DETAILS'    => "$server_url/memberlist.$phpEx?mode=viewprofile&u=$user_id",
                'U_ACTIVATE'        => "$server_url/ucp.$phpEx?mode=activate&u=$user_id&k=$user_actkey")
              );
              $messenger->send($row['user_notify_type']);
            }
            $db->sql_freeresult($result);
          }
        }
        $message = $message . '<br /><br />' . sprintf($user->lang['RETURN_INDEX'], '<a href="' . append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx") . '">', '</a>');
        trigger_error($message);
      }
    }
  }      
}
```

?>

now we add the class to ucp.php

```
    case 'register':
    if ($user->data['is_registered'] || isset($_REQUEST['not_agreed']))
    {
        redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx"));
    }

    $module->load('ucp', 'register');
    $module->display($user->lang['REGISTER']);
break;
case 'my_rails_app_connect':
    if ($user->data['is_registered'])
    {
        redirect(append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx"));
    }

    $module->load('ucp', 'my_rails_app_connect');
    $module->display($user->lang['REGISTER']);
break;
```

Now we add a login for the rails app

create a file called railsapp.php

```
    <?php define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : '../';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
// Load include files.
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.' . $phpEx);
// Set up a new user session.
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup('ucp'); 

$my_rails_user_email = some_code_to_get_user_email_from_rails_database; //maybe use a cookie or make the user allow the phpBB script access to the rails DB or make them login into the rails app

$mysql = 'SELECT user_id
        FROM ' . USERS_TABLE
        . " WHERE user_email='$my_user_rails_email'";
// Execute the query.
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
// Retrieve the row data.
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
// Free up the result handle from the query.
$db->sql_freeresult($result);
// Check to see if we found a user_id with the associated Facebook Id.
if ($row)   // User is registered already, let's log him in!
{
    // Check for user ban.
    if($user->check_ban($row['user_id']))
    {
        trigger_error($user->lang['BAN_TRIGGERED_BY_USER']); 
    }

    // Log user in.
    $result = $user->session_create($row['user_id'], 0, 0, 1);

    // Alert user if we failed to log them in.
    if(!$result)
    {
        trigger_error($user->lang['LOGIN_FAILURE']);
    }

  $redirect = $phpbb_root_path . 'index.' . $phpEx;
  $message = ($l_success) ? $l_success : $user->lang['LOGIN_REDIRECT'];
  $l_redirect = ($admin) ? $user->lang['PROCEED_TO_ACP'] : (($redirect === "{$phpbb_root_path}index.$phpEx" || $redirect === "index.$phpEx") ? $user->lang['RETURN_INDEX'] : $user->lang['RETURN_PAGE']);
  // append/replace SID (may change during the session for AOL users)
  $redirect = reapply_sid($redirect);
  // Special case... the user is effectively banned, but we allow founders to login
  if (defined('IN_CHECK_BAN') && $result['user_row']['user_type'] != USER_FOUNDER)
  {
    return;
  }
  $redirect = meta_refresh(3, $redirect);
  trigger_error($message . '<br /><br />' . sprintf($l_redirect, '<a href="' . $redirect . '">', '</a>'));
}
?>
```

In index_body.html in styles/your_template_name/templates/ add

```
<a href="http://www.myboardurl.com/railsapp.php">Connect With Rails</a>
```

If you need help just drop by [MY phpBB mod support forums to discuss further](http://www.damienkeitel.com)

Comment: also to access the file from within phpBB call http://www.myhref.com/ucp.php?mode=my_rails_app_connect